# How can I instantiate a Robotframework library class with a factory method?

Tags: java, robotframework

I have a Java class which I want to import as a library in my robot file.

The problem is that this class is a singleton with a static method newInstance instead of ordinary public constructor.

Is there any way to tell RobotFramework to use newInstance instead of constructor to instantiate a library object?

Of course, I can use Call Method to get the desired "library" object and then again call its method, but this will disable all the magic and simplicity of direct using of library class methods as keywords.
Making the class a non-singleton is not a solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id691), it is not possible. But you can define the library's scope bysetting `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE` accordingly.

Maybe this helps:

> GLOBAL
>       Only one instance is created during the whole test execution and it is shared by all test cases and test suites. Libraries created from
>   modules are always global.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation reference. There was a intention to utilize an already exitsting Java class with minimal changes and it had no public constructor at all. AFAIR in the end we decided to create an additional class as a mediator specially for using from robotframework.